# Failed to parse URL for a relative, local path

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm using `@react-three/fiber` and `@react-three/drei` to render 3D models in a scene and `npx gltfjsx@6.1.4` to turn .gltf/.glb files to .tsx module-files so that I can import and add them to the scene as per [the react-three-fiber docs.](https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/api/canvas):

```
import * as Models from './models'
import { OrbitControls } from '@react-three/drei/core/OrbitControls.cjs';
    
function Three(){
    return(
        <div style={{height: '100%'}}>
        <Canvas>
            <Suspense fallback={null}>
                <OrbitControls/>
                {Models.Cube}
            </Suspense>
        </Canvas>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Three;
```

In my 'models' folder, I have 3 files: 'Cube.tsx', 'cube-transformed.glb' (both as a result of running gltfjsx) and an index.js with the single line: `export {Model as Cube} from './Cube'`

Here's what Cube.tsx looks like, if you're wondering:

```
/*
Auto-generated by: https://github.com/pmndrs/gltfjsx
Command: npx gltfjsx@6.1.4 cube.gltf --transform --shadows -k -t
*/

import * as THREE from 'three'
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import { useGLTF } from '@react-three/drei'
import { GLTF } from 'three-stdlib'

type GLTFResult = GLTF & {
  nodes: {
    Main_cube: THREE.Mesh
    glowing_tubes: THREE.Mesh
    Cylinder007: THREE.Mesh
    Cylinder007_1: THREE.Mesh
    inner_fdark_cube: THREE.Mesh
  }
  materials: {
    ['main cube']: THREE.MeshStandardMaterial
    cube_pink_light: THREE.MeshStandardMaterial
    ['simple inner cube']: THREE.MeshStandardMaterial
  }
}

export function Model(props: JSX.IntrinsicElements['group']) {
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF('/cube-transformed.glb') as GLTFResult
  return (
    <group {...props} dispose={null}>
      <mesh name="Main_cube" castShadow receiveShadow geometry={nodes.Main_cube.geometry} material={materials['main cube']}>
        <mesh name="glowing_tubes" castShadow receiveShadow geometry={nodes.glowing_tubes.geometry} material={materials.cube_pink_light} position={[0, 0.25, 0]} />
        <group name="Heart_cyl_3_white" position={[0, 0.26, 0]}>
          <mesh name="Cylinder007" castShadow receiveShadow geometry={nodes.Cylinder007.geometry} material={materials['main cube']} />
          <mesh name="Cylinder007_1" castShadow receiveShadow geometry={nodes.Cylinder007_1.geometry} material={materials.cube_pink_light} />
        </group>
        <mesh name="inner_fdark_cube" castShadow receiveShadow geometry={nodes.inner_fdark_cube.geometry} material={materials['simple inner cube']} position={[0, 0.26, 0]} />
      </mesh>
    </group>
  )
}

useGLTF.preload('/cube-transformed.glb')
```

Now, these two lines:

```
const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF('/cube-transformed.glb') as GLTFResult;
useGLTF.preload('/cube-transformed.glb');
```

Throw `TypeError: Failed to parse URL from /cube-transformed.glb`

I tried putting the 'cube-transformed.glb' file in the 'models' directory, as well as the Next.js 'public' directory to no avail.

I'm out of ideas. Why is this happening?

Comment: Can it be a problem with your path? Did you try `./cube-transformed.glb` or maybe start from a folder up `public/cube-transformed.glb` etc

Comment: @cconsta1 I just tried both, still the same error. Even tried to "../" all the way to my root folder then "/public/cube-transformed.glb". Still the same issue. I'm stumped. Could it be a problem that I'm calling the function with eval()?

Comment: Is your model valid, did you try opening it in the three.js editor https://threejs.org/editor/?